# python - concat two dataframe and get over row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1 has 4 columns and 500rows

```
    id  colA colB colC
0   1   4    1    1
1   2   5    2    3
2   5   2    4    2
3   6   3    3    1
.
.
```

df2 has 1 column and 500rows (no NA)

```
  colD 
0 Yes
1 No
2 No
3 No
.
.
```

I wanna get

```
        id  colA colB colC colD 
    0   1   4    1    1    Yes
    1   2   5    2    3    No
    2   5   2    4    2    No
    3   6   3    3    1    No
    .
    .
```

I join df1 and df2 to df3 by

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

But I got more than 500 rows, it's wrong!

So, I use

```
df1["colD"] = df2["colD"]
```

I got the same row but some row in colD is NaN

Answer (score 2):

`concat` aligns your dataframe by index. So if your two dataframes have different index, the result will have more than 500 rows. For example if your `df2` has index `[1,2,3,4]` instead of `[0,1,2,3]` as shown, then

```
pd.concat((df1,df2), axis=1)
```

would give you

```
    id  colA  colB  colC colD
0  1.0   4.0   1.0   1.0  NaN
1  2.0   5.0   2.0   3.0  Yes
2  5.0   2.0   4.0   2.0   No
3  6.0   3.0   3.0   1.0   No
4  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   No
```

If you are certain that `len(df1)==len(df2)` and not so sure about the index, the simplest thing to do is to pass a numpy array to column assignmet, so:

```
df1['colD'] = df2['colD'].values
```

and then `df1` becomes:

```
   id  colA  colB  colC colD
0   1     4     1     1  Yes
1   2     5     2     3   No
2   5     2     4     2   No
3   6     3     3     1   No
```